# How to write Apache Combined Log into mongoDB with custom attributes using fluentd

Tags: apache, mongodb, logging, fluentd

I'm using tail and  [fluent-plugin-mongo](http://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-mongo) to write Apache Combined Log Format into mongoDB but I want to custom some attribute format to write into mongoDB such as

- split path to new attributes from

{

```
ip : 21.18.104.8
host : www.sample.com
message : buildtime=2012_02_14_16_25;version=01.03.3752;totalTimeMin=0;
```

}

to

{

```
ip : 21.18.104.8
host : www.sample.com 
message : buildtime=2012_02_14_16_25;version=01.03.3752;totalTimeMin=0;
buildtime : 2012_02_14_16_25
version : 01.03.3752
totalTimeNin : 0
```

}

- change datetime format from ISODate("2011-11-27T07:56:34Z" to "2011-11-27 07:56:34"
- ceiling timestamp to the nearest 5 minutes eg. 12:33:22 => 12:35:00
- add some function such as from

{

```
ip : 69.249.69.211
host : www.sample.com
message : buildtime=2012_02_14_16_25;version=01.03.3752;totalTimeMin=0;
```

}

to

{

```
ip :  69.249.69.211
country : US
host : www.sample.com
message : buildtime=2012_02_14_16_25;version=01.03.3752;totalTimeMin=0;
```

}

Is that possible to do? I don't have any ideas which plugins I should use.
I've already read docs but I did't get it since it doesn't have many examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend in_tail plugin to achieve your goals. The URL below describes how to do it.

> http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/plugin-development#custom-parser-for-tail-input-plugin

If you have any question, please ask me here or Google Groups. Thanks -K